# How to fix activeX checkboxes moving when opening file

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, worksheet

I know this question have been ask before but I did not find a good answer for me. I can't do the windows updates because this form is used on multiple computers all across the country.

I have 24 checkboxes that are hidden by default and them become visible depending on the combobox value. If I save the file with the checkboxes being hidden, once I open it all the checkboxes will be at one spot(not where they are suppose to be). If I save it with the checkboxes being visible then I open it everything work perfectly fine.

This is the bad one[image: bad]
This is the good one[image: good]

The only way that I got it to work is if I save it with all the checkboxes being hidden then I hide them when workbook is open. This could be a problem if the user does not save it properly. 
Like this

```
 'if the row the row is hidden then the 2 checkboxes on this row are hidden too
 ActiveSheet.Rows("54:101").Hidden = False

 'Hide rows 54 to 101
 ActiveSheet.ComboBox2.Value = ""
 ActiveSheet.ComboBox3.Value = ""
```

I tried changing the object positioning property of the checkboxes but it seems like it has to be `Move but don't size with cells` for it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it myself. My solution is to set a location to a cell for every checkbox like so

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("H65")
With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox223")
    .Top = rng.Top
    .Left = rng.Left
    .Width = rng.Width
    .Height = rng.RowHeight
End With

 Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("J65")
 With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox224")
    .Top = rng.Top
    .Left = rng.Left
    .Width = rng.Width
    .Height = rng.RowHeight
End With

 Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("H69")
 With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox221")
    .Top = rng.Top
    .Left = rng.Left
    .Width = rng.Width
    .Height = rng.RowHeight
End With

 Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("J69")
 With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox222")
    .Top = rng.Top
    .Left = rng.Left
    .Width = rng.Width
    .Height = rng.RowHeight
End With

 Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("H73")
 With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox219")
    .Top = rng.Top
    .Left = rng.Left
    .Width = rng.Width
    .Height = rng.RowHeight
End With

 Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("J73")
 With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox220")
    .Top = rng.Top
    .Left = rng.Left
    .Width = rng.Width
    .Height = rng.RowHeight
End With
```