# Activex checkboxes ghost, move, resize

Tags: excel, checkbox, activex

I have a project (using Excel 2013) that involves using Activex checkboxes and comboboxes.  The comboboxes are fine, but the checkboxes are ghosting over a couple of columns.  I can see the checkbox where it is supposed to be (column W), but when you click it, it vanishes and reappears in column U; when I release the mouse button, it shows where it is supposed to be again.  The exception is the very first checkbox, which shows in column U from the start, and actually works like it's supposed to.

I can manually select them and 'move' them back to where they belong...basically, I select them all, then move them slightly to the side, then back to where they are supposed to be, and they will then work correctly, until the next time I open the document (sometimes they stay put and work fine, sometimes they repeat the ghosting).

I've tried deleting the .xld files as suggested elsewhere, that did not work.  I could not find an 'excel11' file, as someone suggested, and I've tried this: [How to fix activeX checkboxes moving when opening file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146791/how-to-fix-activex-checkboxes-moving-when-opening-file),  also to no avail.  I'm really stuck, this is a fairly involved project, with about 20 of these spreadsheets, and they have worked ok for three years, and now are starting to do this.

So I'm stumped and beyond frustrated, since the changes I was actually brought on to make work fine, when these checkboxes do what they are supposed to do.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The "Fix it for me" download at the following link fixed that issue for me. 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2598310

Comment: This only seems to apply to 2010, I'm using 2013...I tried to run it anyway, it told me that it didn't apply to my version.  I've been poking around to see if something for 2013 is available, nothing yet...

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to establish a left:
        For Each obj In Sheet1.OLEObjects

```
    If (TypeOf obj.Object Is MSForms.CheckBox) And (Left(obj.Name, 8) = OpChxBox) Then
        obj.Object.AutoSize = False
        obj.Top = Rows(CInt(Right(obj.Name, 2)) + 3).Top
        obj.Height = Rows(CInt(Right(obj.Name, 2)) + 3).Height
        obj.Width = Rows(CInt(Right(obj.Name, 2)) + 3).Height
        obj.Left = (Columns("W").Left + Columns("X").Left - obj.Width / 2) / 2
    End If
```

IF that gives you the gist of what I'm trying. I swear I have tried this before, but it seems to be working as of this moment...history tells me that it won't last, so if anyone has any other thoughts, I'd be grateful.